# JIRA SOAP via PHP

Tags: php, soap, jira

I'm trying to connect to the SOAP API on my on-demand version of jira using php.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
$url = JIRA_URL."/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl";
$soapClient = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => TRUE));
$token = $soapClient->login(JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_PASSWORD);
```

Where JIRA_URL is in the format of

```
https://name.atlassian.net.
```

I receive this error when I run the code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("login") is not a valid method for this service
```

I am able to access the confluence SOAP just fine but I use

```
https//name.atlassian.net/wiki
```

and

```
/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v2?wsdl
```

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off use the [REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/). Since you're on a hosted instance it is available. 
The SOAP API will be deprecated soon.

Comment: Certain functions like create project are not avilable with the REST api

Comment: Hmm, you're right... This is strange. The SOAP API is to be deprecated soon. Maybe you should ask the JIRA people over at https://answers.atlassian.com/ .